# Vehicle Can Bus Access

Tags: can-bus

not really sure where to put this, so please direct me elsewhere is this is not a good fit for this question.

I am currently exploring car programming via the OBD2 port. I have been scouring the internet for a OBD2 solution that will allow me to read RAW CAN bus messaged from my car. So far I have not been able to find a software that lets me do this with a ELM327 adapter. Does anyone know if there is software available that can read these A.) with this adapter and B.) Actually show me RAW CAN messages?

So far I have only been able to see the OBD2 messages, but I would like to get under this layer. Any guidance here is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You can solder right into the CAN bus if you can identify the correct wires. There are shields and libraries available for the Arduino that then let you interact with the CAN bus relatively easily. Take care to preserve the CAN bus's continuity, and ensure that you wire in correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your car is recent enough, you won't be able to get the "RAW CAN" traffic. Because behind the OBD port is a gateway that only relay *SOME* of the CAN messages.

You can still get those messages with your ELM but as this device is not made to be a CAN adaptator it can be tricky. You can find a lot of information [here](https://makezine.com/2016/04/08/car-hacking-tools-trade/).

To get more information on what you can find on the CAN bus of the OBD port, you can read [this article](https://www.cowfishstudios.com/blog/canned-pi-part1). It's a good way of having a first overview of the CAN bus in cars.

If you want to have access to the CAN traffic, you will have to do some soldering on your car's wires. Here is [an article](https://medium.com/@alexandreblin/can-bus-reverse-engineering-with-arduino-and-ios-5627f2b1709a) of what it can look like. WARNING : do not perform random stuff on your car, it can be as dangerous as expensive.